# Change password screen. Should we always require the old password?

Tags: android, ios

Consider an application using **OpenIdConnect**. The mobile devices store on their end the access token. My question is about the change password screen. Having a valid access token on the device should we:

1) require the user to enter his current password and twice the new password
**or**
2) we should only require entering the new password twice.

I am aware that it depends on the application and client requirements but if you are building an application for yourself what approach you are going to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a general security practice, I would require entering the old password as well. This adds a layer of protection that confirms the user really is the owner of the account, and not someone who grabbed their phone while the app was open (e.g. their kid, their friend, etc.).

EDIT: I forgot to add this, but this method should have a back-up way of changing the password that provides a similar method of authentication, such as an email they supplied when creating their account. This way, if the user forgets their old password and wants to change it, they can use their email to validate it is them. Send a token (randomly generated numbers/letters) to the address in their account, then require that token to change their password, provided they enter it within a time limit*. After they enter the token, then only allow them to change their password, as opposed to seeing their old password or requiring they enter their old password.

*Note that the token should be sufficiently long (~10 chars) and the time period to enter it be relatively short(~10 min)-this makes it difficult to brute-force accounts.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method , if possible ,

1. if you want to enter the current and new password , then when the user first log's in to app , you have to save username and password in Shared preference or DataBase (normally i use Shared Preferences ) in android and in IOS respective method (i don't no much about ios , i think its UserDetails in ios). and you can make it one time login application, every time you can do login using these details in the background in Splash Screen
   change password screen , you can give current and new password , u can verify old password with the password which is stored in the Shared Preferences if they are same hit Change Password API to server . then on successful change password , change the password in the Shared Preferences also.
2. if you don't want to store the password then you can directly give the new Password and Re-type New password  ,

**its always better to ask the old password.**

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

from my wn knowledge i know that all the big companies including facebook are asking for the old password as descriebed in the first option. the usage of this is to know 100% that you are changing the passwrod and not your little daughter or something that took over the control on youar account**.**to avoid forgettig the password use the first option**.**